# iOS Development/Android : Is it possible to create an app that listens for input in iMessage and interacts with it?

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, imessage

Obviously, the goal is to not use this for malicious purposes but this is part of the app. To clarify, let's say you type in John in iMessage or text messages, does Apple provide a way for an app to listen to your input of 'John' in iMessage or is it against Apple's Policy? (in Swift code)

Comment: I would guess that apple does not like any app that simply logs and listens to every message you send. Neither would I as a user. The goal does not matter here - the simple fact that it *could* be used for malicious purposes is enough to not allow it.

Comment: i don't think that apple allow this kind of operation.

Comment: Indeed, Apple would probably not, what about Android since there is a bit more freedom with Android development?